# Exception in android page curl effect .?

Tags: java, android, curl

I have been doing a simple page curl effect project in android . I refered this site [page curl effect](https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)

> I have imported this project with my local images , At that time
>   Layout inflater exception is coming,, i refered net and solved this
>   adding android.support.v4.jar ... and now class definition not found
>   exception is coming ,, anyway it ll be able to solve ,, but im
>   clearing the exception ,, some another exception is rising ,,  please
>   can anyone help me in this.

this is the change i have made in pagecurlview class.

```
mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1));
    mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page1));
    mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page2));
    mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1));
    mForeground = mPages.get(0);
    mBackground = mPages.get(1);
    mBackground = mPages.get(2);
    mBackground = mPages.get(3);
```

> Did i doing anything wrong in that,,, please can anyone help me in this

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
> activity
> ComponentInfo{com.mystictreegames.pagecurl/com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.StandaloneExample}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error
> inflating class com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error
> inflating class com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
> at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) at
> com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.StandaloneExample.onCreate(StandaloneExample.java:22)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
> ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) ... 22
> more Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502) at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
> at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:378)
> at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:408)
> at
> com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView.init(PageCurlView.java:311)
> at
> com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView.<init>(PageCurlView.java:233)
> ... 25 more
```

Comment: check this logcat error ..

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError`...you are loading too many images.

Comment: Nope... only four images less than 350KB size, but i need to add n number of images.pls suggest me

Comment: You should not init all images at once. Load them only when they are needed.

Comment: in this case of scenario ,in the link which i have shared, how can i load one by one when it is needed ???